# exp(x) for imaginary numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Well, I know how to get the $e^x$ function polynomial expansion, but how do I know that this is also valid for `imaginary numbers`, like $i\pi$?

I know that the **Euler's Formula** is:
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

It means that both the $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ expansions allow na imaginary number like $i\pi$ to be the input. How can I prove this? Is there some good PDF about this?

Comment: Are you asking why the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ is still valid when $x$ is complex?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I want to know why it is still valid

Comment: [Here are some proofs](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler's_Formula) of Euler's formula that don't rely on the Taylor expansion (at least, not directly).  Perhaps you would prefer on of these.

Comment: Compare Euler's [infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Product_representations_of_functions) expression for the [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Properties) $\displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}x=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\left[\frac{x}{n\pi}\right]^2\right)}$ with that of the [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Overview) $\displaystyle{e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n}\left(1+\frac xn\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

Defining the complex exponential is straightforward.

What we want to do is find an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $$f(z_1+z_2) = f(z_1)f(z_2)$$ and $$f(x) = e^x$$
for all real $x$.

Therefore, we have $f(x+iy) = f(x)f(iy) = e^xf(iy)$, where the latter equality comes from the second condition.

Define $f(iy) \equiv M(y)+iN(y)$, which is just another way of saying "break $f$ into real and complex parts." Note that this means that $f(x+iy) = e^xM(y) + e^x iN(y)$. Since we want the function to be analytic, it must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$\begin{align*}
M(y) &= N'(y), \\
M'(y) &= -N(y),
\end{align*}$$
hence, $$M''=-M.$$

Solving this differential equation gives us $M = a \cos y + b \sin y$ and so $N = -M' = a\sin y - b\cos y$.

Now, we use that $f(x) = e^x$ for all real $x$, which is true whenever $y = 0$. Since $M(0) = a$ and $N(0) = -b$, we use $$ e^x = f(x) = f(x+i\cdot 0) = e^xM(0)+e^x iN(0)$$
to conclude that $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Hence, $e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^x \cos y+ ie^x\sin y$.

This is why they Taylor series works.